# how to make the .attr variable

Tags: jquery, attr

As a new jquery noob i'm trying to create a variable .attr instead of copy and pasting all the styles.

What i like to achieve is the following;

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
   var STYLE= attr("class", "btn-outline-danger btn-lg disabled form-control");
   var test = 0;
$('#submit-next').click(function(){
  if (test = '') {       
    $(VARIABLE).STYLE;
  }
});
```

or prehaps

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
   var STYLE= attr("class", "btn-outline-danger btn-lg disabled form-control");
   var VARIABLE = $('#div');       
$('#submit-next').click(function(){
   var test = 0;
   if (test = '') {       
     VIRIABLE.STYLE;
   }
});
```

My code is as following;

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#submit-next').click(function(){ 

var adress = $('#adress').val(); 
var zipcode = $('#zipcode').val(); 
var city = $('#city').val();

if (adress == ''  || zipcode == ''  || city == '') {
       // ADRESS
        if(adress == '')  
        {  
            $('#error_adress').html("Adress is required"); 
            $('#submit-next').attr("data-target","");
            $('#adress').attr("class", "btn-outline-danger btn-lg disabled form-control");

        } else {
            $('#error_adress').html(""); 
            $('#adress').attr("class", "btn-outline-primary btn-lg disabled form-control");
        }

        // ZIPCODE
        if(zipcode == '')  
        {  
            $('#error_zipcode').html("Zipcode is required"); 
            $('#submit-next').attr("data-target","");
            $('#zipcode').attr("class", "btn-outline-danger btn-lg disabled form-control");

        } else {
            $('#error_zipcode').html("");
            $('#zipcode').attr("class", "btn-outline-primary btn-lg disabled form-control"); 
        }

        // CITY
        if(city == '')  
        {  
            $('#error_city').html("City is required"); 
            $('#submit-next').attr("data-target","");
            $('#city').attr("class", "btn-outline-danger btn-lg disabled form-control");

        } else {
            $('#error_city').html(""); 
            $('#city').attr("class", "btn-outline-primary btn-lg disabled form-control");
        }

} else {   
        $('#error_adress').html(""); 
        $('#error_zipcode').html(""); 
        $('#error_city').html("");
        jQuery('#submit-next').attr("data-target","#createclientcontact");   
        }
    });  
});
```

As you can see it's a lot of copy pasting..
I think that this code could be much more compact.

All help would be greatly apprecieted!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can create a function and call it 3 times with address, city and zipcode

Comment: is it possible to add a variable in $('#error_VARIABLE') so i would get all the different selectors? like; #error_adress, #error_city.

Comment: yes, do it like `$('#error_'+VARIABLE)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use more than one way to reduce your code an got befits:

1) You can use toggleClass or addClass and removeClass to update classes nested of set of group of attr classes

2) You can build a function that accept 2 param one for selector and second one for classes and its will be resolve issue

3) You can order code to prevent deplucate and remove unneeded of conditions like set class before condition and when wrong add wrong class.

4) You can save common class in variable

... and more...

in point one you can do this:

```
$('#adress').addClass("btn-lg disabled form-control");
 if(adress == '')  
        {  
$('#adress').addClass("btn-outline-danger").removeClass('btn-outline-primary');
}else{
$('#adress').removeClass("btn-outline-danger").addClass('btn-outline-primary');
}
```

Also You can build like this function:

```
function setClasses(selector, classes){
   $(selector).attr('class', claesses);
}
```

Also you can save common class in variable like this:

```
var commonClass = "btn-lg disabled form-control"
```

Final result for sample code:

```
var commonSuccessClass = "btn-outline-primary btn-lg disabled form-control";
var commonWrongClass   = "btn-outline-danger btn-lg disabled form-control";
if(adress == '')  
            {  
                $('#error_adress').html("Adress is required"); 
                $('#submit-next').attr("data-target","");
                setClasses('#selector', commonWrongClass);
            } else {
                $('#error_adress').html(""); 
                setClasses('#selector', commonSuccessClass);
            }
```

and a lot of other solution ...

Answer (score 0):

This is how i reduced your code. You can check by running the code snippet.

> PS: I assumed that you are using input tags, that is why i used `$("input:not('#submit-next')").each( function(el, ind)` But depending on your code, this part may be changed.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#submit-next').click(function(){
     $("input:not('#submit-next')").each( function(el, ind) {
      let content = $(this).val();
      let elm = $(this).attr('id');
      if (!content.length) {
       $("#error_"+elm).html(elm+" is required");
       $('#submit-next').attr("data-target","");
       $(elm).attr("class", "btn-outline-danger btn-lg disabled form-control");
      } else {
             $("#error_"+elm).html("");
             $(elm).attr("class", "btn-outline-primary btn-lg disabled form-control");
      }
     });
    });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="adress">
<input type="text" id="zipcode">
<input type="text" id="city">
<input type="button" id="submit-next" name="submit-next" value="submit-next">
<p id="error_adress"></p>
<p id="error_zipcode"></p>
<p id="error_city"></p>
```

Comment: thank you for the comment, could you tell me whta the function(el, ind) are for?

Comment: There is actually no need to pass any parameters such as `(el, ind)` to this function. It is just an habit. But if you are asking.what this function does, it iterates each of the inputs which are not submit button, and does exactly what you did with a bunch of code.